# Javascript Date - convert date to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX format

Tags: javascript

I was looking for it but could not find any documentation of examples.

I there a function in the native `Date` in Javascript which is able to convert date to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` format?

I found a way to do it via `date-fns`

```
datefns.format(new Date(year, month, day), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

But I prefer to use a native function if that's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString - this?

Comment: JS has very few native functions to deal with dates. Only the essentials, basically. I strongly recommend using a library to deal with dates. It will spare you a lot of work. I recommend https://momentjs.com/.

Comment: `.toJSON()`. It internally uses `toISOString()`, but will output `null` when you use it on an invalid date. `toISOString()` will either return a wrong date string or throw an error.

Comment: @georg it's not ISO string

Comment: @Taki the format I require is not ISO string

Comment: @PedroLima, I guess I will use a library

Comment: What does XXX stand for if not the timezone?

Comment: @DavidFaiz So you want to get an ISO datestring without milliseconds?